# Syncfusion HTML To PDF conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, syncfusion, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm facing with an interesting problem. I use Syncfusion Essential Studio + Web Kit for converting HTML to a PDF. Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes it is completely useless.

What means completely useless? It throws UnauthorizedException, every time, when I call HtmlToPdfConverter's Convert method. But it doesn't occur every time, just appears randomly. 
Here is my code:

```
        string htmlString = "";

        try
        {   // Open the text file using a stream reader.
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("PdfTemplates\\template.html"))
            {
                // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                htmlString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Error(e,"read the template html");
            throw e;
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(htmlString);

        sb.Replace("%SOMETHING%", something);
        htmlString = sb.ToString();

        _logger.Information("htmltemplate with new data created");

        PdfDocumentBase mergedPdf;
        try
        {
            var pdfDocFromHtml = _htmlConverter.Convert(htmlString, ""); // THE Problematic line
            var pdfLoadedDocument = new PdfLoadedDocument(uploadedPdfStream);

            //template generation
            _logger.Information("pdf created from html");

             //merge the generated pdf with the uploaded document
             mergedPdf = MergePdf(pdfDocFromHtml, pdfLoadedDocument);

             _logger.Information("pdf merged");

             var resultStream = PdfDocumentToStream(mergedPdf);

            pdfDocFromHtml.Close(true);
            pdfLoadedDocument.Close(true);

                    return resultStream;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Type typeOfE = ex.GetType();
            _logger.Error(ex, "pdfLoadedDocument from byteArray");
            throw;
        }
```

I work in a team, and none of the teammates has the problem, just me. I'm on Windows 10 Pro. We're developing an ASP.NET MVC application.

Does somebody have an idea what can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to reproduce the unauthorized exception while converting HTML string to PDF using MVC application in Windows 10 environment, but it is working fine. We have not faced similar exceptions earlier, Could you create a new incident through Syncfusion Direct-Trac support system with the below details.

1. Code snippet or a sample to reproduce the issue.
2. Input HTML file or URL.
3. Environment details about the Operating System and language specification.

Meanwhile, please try converting some other URL (http://www.google.com) to PDF using the same project and let me know the result.

**Note:** I work for Syncfusion

Comment: I tried to convert http://www.google.com, but it failed, too. I'll contact with the support, too.